# What would cause the social connector inside of outlook 2013 to not show information?

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am working on trying to figure out why some of our Outlook 2013 clients will not display any information about internal users inside the Outlook Social Connector plugin.

The plugin appears to work fine with Outlook 2010 which is what is on my workstation. The issues seems to only be with Outlook 2013 systems.

To clarify what I mean is the social connector at the bottom of each email does not show any content when the user is part of our network / exchange server. However if the user is part of an external network / server we see content in the social connector.

Examples;

This is a picture of the Outlook Social Plugin being displayed on an email from an internal user.

[image: Internal User]

See how it says there is no content.

Here is an email from an external email account.

[image: External User]

See how it shows content related to the user. We are trying to figure out why it refuses to do that for internal users using Outlook 2013.

I have been up and down Google trying various registry keys with no avail. Some parts of solutions involved checking group policy since we are on a domain. While this is still being investigated to my knowledge we don't have the ADMX files installed to manage this feature via GPO.

Any ideas?